# Cake PHP 2.x system logout after PHP upgrade

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I upgraded PHP version to 7 for the system(cake PHP 2.x) few days back, I have mainly updated library files of framework. After it users are experiencing problem of logging out while they try to fill any data, while opening new links in system etc. That is very random, same form sometimes get submit without any issue and sometime end user to login page. I have tried some solution and this is what I have added in **core.php**

```
> Configure::write('Session', array(         'defaults' => 'php',
>         'timeout' => 1440,
>         'autoRegenerate' => true,//resets session on activity
>         'checkAgent' => false,
>         'cookieTimeout' => 1440   ));
```

According to this system should not logout soon or in few minutes, still that issue is happening, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

PHP also has a session timeout setting (`session.gc_maxlifetime`). If it's less than Cake's, then Cake's settings won't really matter, the session will timeout based on PHP's settings. Guessing that there was a custom value for this in your previous version of PHP, and it didn't get moved over to your new version's ini file. Beware that PHP's setting is in seconds, but Cake's is in minutes.

Comment: Thanks. Old setting ( PHP 5.6)also has value of 1440 for session.gc_maxlifetime. I have checked again and it is same now for PHP 7.x.

Comment: Also, other point is, it is happening while user is active on the system.